# shell script to find unique value and extract each value into separate variable

Tags: shell-script

Have a file1 with vname and vport

```
Vname vport
xyc    3:4:7
sdf    5:5:5
sft    5:5:5
sfg    3:4:7
szd    1:2:3
```

Get the unique port

```
vport 1:2:3
```

and separate and assign each of them to a variable like a=1, b=2, c=3

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to achieve. Can you give more detailed example?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you are looking for a line starting with `szd` and then want to read the corresponding `vport` value into the three variables?

Comment: When you say "get unique port", does that mean no `a` can be equal to a `b` or `c`? Or `a`/`b`/`c` should be unique regardless of each others?

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
#!/bin/bash

# IFS is a special enviroment variable. The character in it will be used
# by 'read' (which is a bash builtin command).
#
# In this case we need space and colon as separators
#
IFS=' :'

# Looping over lines in the file, fo each line read name, a, b, and c.

# "sed 1d" command deletes first line to skip over header ("Vname vport")
#
sed 1d file1 | while read name a b c ; do

    # If it was an empty line, skip and loop to next line
    #
    [ "$name" ] || continue

    # output the variables for demonstration
    #
    echo "name: $name"
    echo "a = $a"
    echo "b = $b"
    echo "c = $c"

    # extra line to separate output of next line
    #
    echo

done
```

Comment: I am curious: since you alread specified `IFS`, why don't you just use `while read name a b c; do <...> done`?

Comment: No real reason, just me doing it overly complex :)
Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to identify that `vport` combination which only occurs once in the file, and want to split that into the three variables `a`, `b` and `c`. In this case, you could make use of associative arrays:

The following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A counts   # declare `counts` as associative container

# Read the file line-wise
while read vname vport
do
    if [[ "$vname" == "Vname" ]]; then continue; fi # skip header

    # if current 'vport' value not yet encountered, add it to the array
    # with count=1, otherwise increment the value
    if [[ -z "${counts[$vport]}" ]]
    then
        counts[$vport]=1
    else
        let counts[$vport]=${counts[$vport]}+1
    fi
done < file.txt


# Identify which one only occurs once: iterate over all "keys" and
# check which "value" is "1"
found=0
for vp in "${!counts[@]}"
do
    # If such a key was found, split it at the ':' and read the parts
    # into individual variables
    if [[ "${counts[$vp]}" == "1" ]]
    then
        IFS=":"
        read a b c <<< "$vp"
        found=1
        break
    fi
done


# Output the variables if a unique port specification was found
if (( found == 1 ))
then
    echo "Unique port found: a=$a, b=$b, c=$c"
else
    echo "No unique port found!"
fi
```

**Note** that this assumes there is **only one such unique port** (which seems reasonable to guess from your example).