# script to remove duplicates values and assigh values to variable

Tags: shell-script

Have a File as below need to filter the duplicate values and assigh values to a variables

```
name    port
xyc    3:4:7
sdf    5:5:5
sft    5:5:5
sfg    3:4:7
szd    1:2:3
```

Output File

```
Port
3:4:7
5:5:5
1:2:3
```

next values should be assigned like below in loop

```
First Iteration :  a=4 b= 4 c=7
Second Iteration   a=5 b=5 c=5
Thirtd iteration   a=1 b=2 c=3
```

Comment: Apart from the "unique" bit, an exact duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552119/shell-script-to-find-unique-value-and-extract-each-value-into-separate-variable

Comment: Is it possible that the port numbers can be double digits or greater? for example: `15:4:255`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=~/tmp/input
output=~/tmp/output
ports=($(awk '$2 !~ "port"{print $2}' input | sort -u))

printf '%s\n' 'Port' > "$output"
printf '%s\n' "${ports[@]}" >> "$output"

for p in "${ports[@]}"; do
    a=$(awk -F\: '{print $1}' <<<"$p")
    b=$(awk -F\: '{print $2}' <<<"$p")
    c=$(awk -F\: '{print $3}' <<<"$p")
    printf 'a=%s, b=%s, c=%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
done
```

---

This will create an array called `ports` with the unique values from column 2 (minus the literal string `port`, since if left it probably won't sort to the top for you and apparently you want to capitalize the first letter in your output file anyway.

Then we create an output file with the word `Port` on top, then we add all the unique port values from the input file to the new output file.

Then we loop through each value in the `ports` array and set the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` to the first, second, and third column respectively.   `awk` is being used here because I'm not sure if your port numbers can be multiple digits so this method would handle it either way, but if they will always be single digits you could use shell parameter expansion which should be a bit faster:

```
a=${p:0:1}
b=${p:2:1}
c=${p:4:1}
```